# How to change fab:fab_title color of FloatingActionButton in android

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

Here is a simple **FloatingActionButton** to display a floating button and set a title "fab:fab_title". I want to change the color of this
fab:fab_title.

```
 <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_floating_newest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/twitter_blue"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/twitter_blue"
        fab:fab_icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        fab:fab_title="@string/newest" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [FloatingActionButton code](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/getbase/floatingactionbutton/FloatingActionButton.java) you probably need to call something like this:

```
myFloatingButton.findViewWithTag(R.id.fab_label).setTextColor(myNewColor);
```

Basically what is done in the [`getLabelView()`](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/getbase/floatingactionbutton/FloatingActionButton.java#L216) method.

You can also overwrite the class and create your own methods so set the color.
There is also a [pull request](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/pull/264/commits/f9d18c37576dde9f92f4ae334dc925e8e639304d) for that feature already but not merged.

Anyway you should look for a more updated library, this one wasn't touched in 2 years.

Answer (score 1):

Im not on my PC right now, but I handled it with

```
app:backgroundTint="#00000000"
```

in the XML File

The number in "" stands for the hexadecimal code of your color
I'm pretty sure this would work.

And the change on click you have to change within the programming.
It's done with

```
fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("your hexadecimal color")));
```

You have to put this in the first Line of the OnClickListener Code of your FAB

Comment: I'm not sure `00000000` is a good example, considering the opacity of 0

Comment: I'm talking about text color instead of button color.

Comment: then try android:tint="your hexadecimal color" in the code ... and like another poster said: try another library maybe <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>